# MongoDb aggregate full text search doesn't return id field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, full-text-search, aggregate

I implement full text search in my Mongo database.
When I try to search over my index with aggregate, the results is good but the id is missing.

```
models.Piece.aggregate([
    {
      $searchBeta: {
        "index": "search-piece",
        "search": {
          "query": search,
          "path": ["name", "styles"],
          "phrase": { prefix: true },
        },
      },
    },
    {
      $skip: offset,
    },
    {
      $limit: limit,
    },
  ]);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GI0KG.png)

Comment: what do you mean by id is missing ? Is it about `_id` or `id:null` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve the problem.
The problem was from graphql and mongodb aggregation.
I had to write a resolve specific for the id field.

```
  Piece: {
    id: (parent, args, { models }) => parent._id,
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Use $project as the end stage. Project the fields required.